# Python user input and date conversion

Tags: python

I'm trying to create this program for class but I have a tiny issue. I always seem to have problems with loops! The program works if you enter the date as asked, but I can't get it to go back and ask the user for the date again if the input is wrong. I created the True/False boolean but it doesn't seem to work. We haven't learned how to import certain date modules and convert so I'm converting the months manually.

Instructions:

A. Input a date in numeric format from the user e.g. mm/dd/yy.

B. Examine the month entered by the user. If it is larger than 12 or smaller than 1 issue an error message and ask for input again.

C. Perform similar validation tests for the date and year.    Year must 
be 2013. (Any other year is invalid). In addition, the year must only be two digits long.

D. Once all the input has been validated, output the string in long date format. Thus a string that was input at 06/01/15 will be output as June 1, 2015.

```
def main():
    try_again = True
    while try_again == True:
        date_string = input("Please enter a date in the format 'mm/dd/yy': ")
        date_list = date_string.split('/')

        month = date_list[0]
        day = date_list[1]
        year = date_list[2]

        if month > "12" or month < "01":
            print('Error, please re-enter the date!')

        if year != '13':
            print('Error! The year must be 2013')

        if len(year) > 2:
            print('Error! The year can only be 2 digits long!')

        else:
            print_date(month, day, year)
            try_again = False



def print_date(month, day, year):

# Convert to 2013 because 2013 is the only valid year
# for this program.

if year == '13':
    year = '2013' 

# Convert the number values to the actual month.

if month == '01':
    month = 'January'
if month == '02':
    month = 'February'  
if month == '03':       
    month = 'March'
if month == '04':
    month = 'April'
if month =='05':
    month = 'May'
if month == '06':
    month = 'June'
if month == '07':
    month = 'July'
if month == '08':
    month = 'August'
if month == '09':
    month = 'September'
if month =='10':
    month = 'October'
if month == '11':
    month = 'November'
if month == '12':
    month = 'December'


# Print the date in the correct format 
print(month + " " + day + ',' + " " + year)


main()
```

Comment: instead of extra `if` statements, don't you want `elif` statements?

Comment: just a warning: comparing `month` against the strings `'01'` and `'12'` is not going to guarantee it is a valid input: `'01' < "0asb" < '12' ==> True`

Comment: you'd be better off checking `if not ( month.isdigit() and 1 <= int(month) <= 12)`

Answer (score 1):

the `else` is only on the last `if` statement, either add `continue` to each conditional or change the middle `if` to `elif`:

```
    if month > "12" or month < "01":
        print('Error, please re-enter the date!')
        continue #back to beginning of loop

    if year != '13':
        print('Error! The year must be 2013')
        continue #back to beginning of loop

    if len(year) > 2:
        print('Error! The year can only be 2 digits long!')
        continue #back to beginning of loop

    #else: #doesn't really change anything any more
    #only happens if none of the continue s happend
    print_date(month, day, year)
    try_again = False
```

or with `elif`s:

```
    if month > "12" or month < "01":
        print('Error, please re-enter the date!')

    elif year != '13':
        print('Error! The year must be 2013')

    elif len(year) > 2:
        print('Error! The year can only be 2 digits long!')

    else:
        print_date(month, day, year)
        try_again = False
```

That way only one of the conditionals will happen.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked this mistake. Thank you

Comment: If you accept an answer there is [a mechanism for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).